# No instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that void conforms to U

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, option-type

I am trying to avoid `isPresent` checks in my code below, but the compiler emits an error with the message

> "No instance(s) of type variable(s) `U` exist so that `void` conforms to `U`"

on the call to `printAndThrowException`. This is my code:

```java
values.stream()
    .filter(value -> getDetails(value).getName.equals("TestVal"))
    .findFirst()
    .map(value -> printAndThrowException(value))
    .orElseThrow(new Exception2("xyz"));
```

The method in question printAndThrowException has the below signature:

```java
void printAndThrowException(Pojo value)
```

The above method always throws an exception of type `RuntimeException`. The abovementioned code isn't the exact code, just transformed my code to represent the situation.

What's the problem here and how to avoid using `isPresent` when calling `printAndThrowException`?

Comment: You have to provide a bit more details on the types of variables (`values`) and what each step in the stream pipeline returns and in which step do you get this error

Comment: `orElseThrow` should take a supplier. So, it will be `.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception2(..))`

Comment: @user7 : Added more details. Also, orElseThrow does not show any error, error is on the call to printAndThrowException.

Comment: Does `printAndThrowException` *always* throw an exception?

Comment: `map()` is used to *convert* one value to another value- not the case here - this use case seems more like a case for `ifPresentOrElse()` (Java 9 or later)

Comment: @MCEmperor : In my case, yes. If you have any better suggestions; please suggest

Comment: @MCEmperor I realised that It would be cleaner to call the method in ifPresent and throw exception at the call place itself :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Optional.map()` expects a `Function<? super T, ? extends U>` as parameter. Since your method returns `void`, it cannot be used like this in the lambda.

I see three options here:

- make that method return `Void`/`Object`/whatever instead – semantically not ideal but it would work
- make that method return the exception, and change the lambda definition to

  ```
  .map(v -> {
      throw printAndReturnException();
  });
  ```
- use `ifPresent()`, and move the `orElseThrow()` outside of the call chain:

  ```
  values.stream()
      .filter(value -> getDetails(value).getName.equals("TestVal"))
      .findFirst()
      .ifPresent(value -> printAndThrowException(value))
  throw new Exception2("xyz");
  ```